# Poisson fixed effects model in pglm estimating time-invariant predictor

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, poisson-regression, quasi-likelihood

I am analyzing panel data on various municipalities (id_mun) over several years using the pglm package in R. My dataset contains a variable "treatment" which is continuous but is time-invariant within each municipality. I have fit a fixed effects (within) Poisson regression model to account for unobserved time-invariant characteristics at the municipality level. The model also includes year dummies, the variable treatment, and interaction terms between treatment and the year indicators, along with an offset term.

My understanding is that in a fixed effects model, time-invariant variables should be absorbed by the fixed effects and not be estimated. However, when I run the pglm model, I'm seeing a coefficient estimate for "tratment".

Here is the code I am using to fit the model:

````
model_formula_2 <- as.formula(paste("total_deaths ~ ", paste(c("yr_i_2011", "yr_i_2012", "yr_i_2013", "yr_i_2014", "yr_i_2015", "yr_i_2016", "yr_i_2017", "yr_i_2019", "treatment", 
paste0("treatment_", c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2019"))), collapse = " + "), " + offset(log(ratebirths))"))

df_deaths_panel <- pdata.frame(df_deaths_panel, index = c("id_mun","yr_i"))

# Fit the plm model
model <- pglm(model_formula_2, data = df_deaths_panel, family = poisson(link = "log"), model = "within", effect = "individual") ```

Why is pglm estimating a coefficient for a time-invariant variable in a fixed effects model? Is there something I might be overlooking or could this be related to a specific feature of the pglm function? (I already revise that the variable "treatment" is effectively time invariant)
````

Comment: Welcome. Would it be possible to share a small subset of your data?